# TinyMCE 4.6.3 Support IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer-10, tinymce-4

I have used TinyMCE 4.6.3 along with angular JS. Now It is working Fine with IE=Edge, but when I tried to used the same in IE 10, it is only showing the blank `<textarea></textarea>`. Can anybody please help?

Please find my Configuration file as follows.

```
var tinyOpt = {
                    selector: 'textarea',
                    menubar:false,
                    statusbar: true,
                    toolbar:false,
                    plugins:['autoresize'],
                    readonly:true,
                    autoresize_bottom_margin:10,
                    autoresize_on_init: true          
};
```

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 3):

TinyMCE 4.6 does not support any version of IE prior to IE 11.  This is documented on the TinyMCE documentation site:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/system-requirements/

> Since TinyMCE version 4.6.0 Internet Explorer 8-10 is no longer supported, if you still need legacy browser support the 4.5.X branch will be maintained with critical fixes.

I would note that 4.5 is getting critical fixes but those are very few in number.  No new features/functions are being added to TinyMCE 4.5 at this point in time.